# ant diagnostics to a sepate file?

Tags: ant

can we print ant diagnostics result to separate file?
I am using,

```
<target name="diagnostics" description="diagnostics" >
    <diagnostics/>
</target>
```

It is printing in the console.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can figure to do it is to call the target from inside an  task in another target and have it dump the output into a text file.

```
<project name="help" default="help">
   <target name="diagnostics">
       <diagnostics/>
   </target>

    <target name="help">
        <ant output="diag.txt" target="diagnostics"/>
    </target>
</project>
```